# Should I / how do I clear a mousemove JQuery event listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use

```
$(".page").mousemove(function(event){});
```

As soon as the `mouseup` event comes, I no longer need this listener. Since I'll be applying the listener repetitively for different actions, it seems to me that these listeners *might* stick around and build up (needlessly wasting CPU) as the user activates the function many times. I'm not really sure how this works internally, that's just my guess.

**Should I / how do I clear a mousemove JQuery event listener?**

Comment: In `mouseup` event handler, use `$(this).off('mousemove');` or if more than one element `$('.page').off('mousemove');`, depending expected behaviour. But it sounds like an XY problem, why are you binding it more than once?

Comment: Because the variables/elements involved are reached/created during a function, so the listener needs to happen during a function since it has nothing to attach to until the function begins.

Comment: @A.Wolff Good idea, thanks for showing me that.

Comment: Oops i deleted by mistake comment, so i repost it: `Sounds like you'd have better to use delegation:` https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code:

```
$('.page').off('mousemove');
```

But please note that the following approach turns off all functions firing on `mousemove`. If you want to turn off a prticular function then you should do the following:

```
// Define function that fires on mousemove
function anyFunctionName () {
    // Some code
}

// Set listener
$('.page').on('mousemove', anyFunctionName);

// Turn off only function called funcionName
$('.page').off('mousemove', anyFunctionName);
```

Another way for turning off a particular function would is defining a name for the event:

```
// Define function that fires on mousemove
function anyFunctionName () {
    // Some code
}

// Set listener
$('.page').on('mousemove.anyEventName', anyFunctionName);

// Turn off only function fired on event called anyEventName
$('.page').off('mousemove.anyEventName');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a working example using the more general `.on` and `.off` JQuery functions instead of their explicit handlers.  Here is the code I used:

```
$('.page').on('mousedown', function() {
    $(this).on('mousemove', function(event) {
        // Do something meaningful
    });
});
$('.page').on('mouseup', function() {
    $(this).off('mousemove');
});
```

Here is a [JFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2u8uLb51/) of it.